# erreur when running instaloader with the module `ContextManager`

Tags: python-3.x

when i start instaloader with python 3.5 i get this error with `ContextManager`, i found nothing on the web that helped, the os is `rasbian 9`

```
traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/instaloader/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .instaloader import Instaloader
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/instaloader/instaloader.py", line 16, in <module>
    from typing import Any, Callable, ContextManager, IO, Iterator, List, Optional, Set, Union, cast
ImportError: cannot import name 'ContextManager'
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed 2 days ago: https://github.com/instaloader/instaloader/pull/777

Use --pre to install the pre-release version